# Generating Source Info For Flex BitmapData

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, air

Instead of populating the BitmapData class from an IMAGE.  I would like to (within Actionscript) GENERATE some new BitmapData by capturing the Bitmap representing say, a TextArea component on the stage.

In other words, sort of take a "screen capture" or "screenshot" of one of the components, and convert that into an image.  Am I silly to even wonder if such a thing is feasible?  Can an Air/Flex app "look at itself" in this way?  Can it turn a datagrid or a canvas or a textinput into the corresponding image AS IF via screen capture?

Even a hint in the right direction would be appreciated,

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/12/07/using-the-imagesnapshot-class-to-capture-images-as-jpegs-or-pngs-in-flex-3/

If you want to take the screenshot of particular component, then you need to use the BitMapData class and calculate pixel by pixel by drawing it.